# Paste the same blck of data below its self twice (or more)

Tags: vba, excel, copy, paste

I'm working on a formatting project for a monthly template.  The data in column "E" will be static in each work book but different in other workbooks I'll run the macro on. IE one workbook may have 10K rows in column "E" and another workbook could have 20K in column "E".  I need to copy that block of text below its self 2x.  So I have a triplication of all that data from "E2:E".

I'm not looking for HUGE solutions with a million unnecessary Dimed variables. I'm close.  What am I missing?

```
 Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Select
   Selection.Copy
   Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1).Paste<------ ERROR!
```

Becoming frustrated.

Comment: Have you tried recording the very steps you want to take and then putting them in a macro? Since the steps are the same each time (click E2, Ctrl+Down, Ctrl+C, Down, Ctrl+V, etc.) it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: I need it to go to the next blank cell.  when I use the down arrow again it records the actual cell.  How to get it to recognize "+1"?

Comment: To pick the cell below (the recorded macro was using `Range("E##")` which wouldn't be known), I used `Range("E" + CStr(ActiveCell.Row + 1)).Select` after the xlDown. But, @tim-williams answer is beautifully elegant.

Answer (score 4):

Using < 1million variables...

```
With ActiveSheet
    With .Range(.Range("E2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
        .Copy .Offset(.Rows.Count, 0)
        .Copy .Offset(.Rows.Count * 2, 0)
    End With
End With
```

Comment: lol I'm sure you also have a solution with those 1M variables :D

Comment: I'm not seeing how to make this work in the whole.  I've already got the correct data copying.  Should that be ".paste"

Answer (score 0):

Compared to @Tim-Williams answer, this feels positively hideous. However, I present to you:

```
Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Copy
For idx = 1 To 2
    Cells(Range("E2").End(xlDown).Row + 1, "E").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Next
```

Comment: The above works perfectly.  Question.  why is copy paste hated so much?  the copied data set can be as high as 250000 items or more.  would that cause a problem?  I must be tired but i'm not getting Tims to work.  Im sure it is me.

Comment: Why the hate for copy-paste? No idea. Glad the above worked! Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

the following is almost there:

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
```

I just need it to drop down 1 and paste that, THEN drop to the NEXT blank row and paste it again.

Comment: I suggest you consider Tim's solution which avoids you the very unpopular `Select-Copy-Paste` idiom.

Answer (score 0):

my 0.02 cents

- `Range.Value` approach (pasting values only)

  ```
  With Range("E2", Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
      .Offset(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value
      .Offset(.Rows.Count * 2).Value = .Value
  End With
  ```
- formula approach (and pasting values only)

  ```
  With Range("E2", Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
      .Offset(.Rows.Count).Resize(.Rows.count * 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[" & -.Rows.Count & "]C" '<--| have 2x referenced range cells below it with its values
      .Resize(.Rows.Count * 2).Value = .Resize(.Rows.Count * 2).Value '<--| get rid of formulas
  End With
  ```
- Copy/PasteSpecial approach (you can choose what to paste - see [PasteSpecial()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476(v=office.15).aspx) method)

  ```
  With Range("E2", Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
      .Copy
      .Offset(.Rows.Count).Resize(.Rows.Count * 2).PasteSpecial ' you have some options like xlPasteAll (pastes all) or xlPasteValues (pastes values only)and others 
      Application.CutCopyMode = False '<--| this to free clipboard and clear highlighted cells
  End With
  ```